# Unable to edit properties of previously edited text

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Added some text to with the text tool and was able to edit the font style and size. Saved the project but now when clicking on the text unable to get the property options like before in order to change the font and size of the text. Where did the properties for the text go?

With new text I get the Character options but when clicking the old text none of those options are available. I just get the Quick Actions with no way of editing. I can add additional text and edit that but I want to see what font size I had chosen previously. How can I change the font size and style of an already saved .ai file? Thank you.

Comment: Unclear question. Open the file, click the text box, hit CTRL+T and show us that screenshot.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have the text inside a group?  You need to select just the text box. Can you please show us a screen shot showing the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Properties panel is incomplete. To edit text attributes, use Command-T on a Mac or Contrl-T on Windows to show the **Character** panel. You can also view this panel from **Window > Type > Character.** Select your text with the Text tool, and you should be able to edit its properties in that panel.